# Mklink to a password protected folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mklink

I have machine A and a C$ share on machine B.

On machine B, I only have access to the share and nothing else (it is password protected). How can I mklink from machine A to the C$ share invoking username and password for C$?